# Is there any built in self upgrade command for upgrading in PowerShell 7.x?

Tags: powershell, upgrade, powershell-core

I've recently installed PoweShell 7.1.1 on my fresh Windows 10 computer (19042).
Now when I start it it says a new stable is available 7.1.2, upgrade now or check the release page.

**Question**

Is there a built in self upgrade command, or I just go to the release page, download the latest release and run the installer? (this latter case will it correctly *upgrade*, or just overwrites, or something else, resulting side effects?)

Comment: nope! there is no such thing. they have published a script that does the job ... but it is not included with the install.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7.1

***6 Options.***

```
# 1 - Install PowerShell Core
Invoke-Expression -Command "& { $(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1') } -UseMSI" 
# https://enterinit.com/cs/powershell-7-preview-install-and-upgrade
# Save the above script and run as needed.

# 2 - Via a module
Install-Module -name PSReleaseTools -Force
Install-PSPreview -mode Quiet
# https://adamtheautomator.com/updating-to-powershell-7

# 3 - Install-Powershell
install-powershell.ps1 -Daily
# https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/tools/install-powershell.ps1

# 4 - From a cmdlet
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1' | 
New-Item -Path function: -Name Install-PowerShell | 
Out-Null

<#
It creates a new cmdlet Install-PowerShell with a number of useful parameters. 
For example, to download the latest production version of PowerShell 7 as a 
portable app in a folder of your choice, run this:
#>
Install-PowerShell -Destination 'c:\ps7test' -AddToPath

<#
If you prefer to install PowerShell 7 as a managed MSI application, run this 
instead:.
#>
Install-PowerShell -UseMSI -Quiet

# Note: A truly quiet installation requires Administrator privileges.

# 5 - Chocolaty
choco install powershell-core -y
# https://chocolatey.org/packages/powershell-core

# 6 - Linux
wget -O - https://aka.ms/install-powershell.sh | sudo bash
# https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/03/how-to-install-and-update-powershell-6
```

Comment: This answer could use some additional explanation and to be updated to use modern names. For example, am I supposed to understand what option 3 is doing? Given that option 1 mentions “PowerShell Core”, I can only assume that option 3 is installing Windows PowerShell (and “Core” is a name that appears to no longer be in use except where people forgot to remove it from help files). Another example: I am not confident that some of these will upgrade PowerShell rather than installing a new instance.

Comment: @randy-Cragun...   Every option presented in the response is for the latest version of PowerShell. Not  Windows Powershell. You cannot install Windows PowerShell, as it is built-in to the OS (you can upgrade from v1-v5.1). `There are no more builds of Windows PowerShell since it is depreciated.` You can only install PowerShell Core. Despite whatever name etymology in the options, it's all PowerShell Core.  The shorter name does not change its taxonomy `https://github.com/powershell/powershell`. Windows PowerShell == powershell.exe/PowerShell_ISE.exe, PowerShell Core/PowerShell is pwsh.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the easiest way to upgrade PowerShell on Windows 10/11 is using the builtin winget tool.

```
winget upgrade --id Microsoft.PowerShell --exact --silent --scope machine
```